# How to append the same object to relationship in (Flask) SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

The problem I'm running into is that when I try to append the same (Flask SQLAlchemy) object to a relationship, I'm pretty sure it just skips the duplicate.

My use case is that a `Code` can have double color objects in it. This works fine with the database as you can see here:

```
+----+----------+---------+
| id | color_id | code_id |
+----+----------+---------+
| 17 | 5        | 5       |
+----+----------+---------+
| 18 | 4        | 5       |
+----+----------+---------+
| 19 | 5        | 5       |
+----+----------+---------+
| 20 | 6        | 5       |
+----+----------+---------+
```

`color_id` 5 is present twice for the same code.

But as I mentioned earlier it doesn't work as smoothly with relationships.

The relationship inside my `Code` class looks like this:

```py
_colors = db.relationship('Color', secondary=colors, lazy='subquery', backref=db.backref('code_colors', lazy=True))
```

Which works perfectly fine except when I try to append the same object twice like this:

```py
random_code.colors.append(color_list[i])
```

It appends all colors except the extra double color.
Using the debugger this becomes very clear.

Below you can see that the list correctly has all the color objects I want to append including the same object twice.

[image: What's actually inside the list]

But this is what it actually appends AFTER THE `db.session.commit()`

[image: What's actually inside the code.colors]

I have searched the internet but found no results where they are appending to a relationship. How can I fix this so it appends all the color objects instead of filtering out the duplicates?